# Open URL from custom info window, Android Google Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using android google maps api v2 with many markers displayed on it. Each time you click on a marker a custom info window with specific tittle/snippet is open. The problem is that I cannot click on the URL "www.news.com". 
Please find below the options of my marker. How can I specify that the "www.news.com" is a HTML URL link inside the .snippet attribute, and when user clicking on it to open directly in mobiles explorer?

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(39.686286, 19.838443))
        .title("HELLO")
        .snippet("Name: \nSurname: \nphone: XXX \nwebsite: www.news.com")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location_icon)));
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#info_window_events) (my emphasis):

> As mentioned in the previous section on info windows, an info window is not a live View, rather the view is rendered as an image onto the map. As a result, any listeners you set on the view are disregarded **and you cannot distinguish between click events on various parts of the view**. You are advised not to place interactive components — such as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom info window.

The url cannot be clicked separately from the info window as a whole. You may consider assigning a [click listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener.html) to the info window itself, and navigating to the appropriate webpage whenever the info window is clicked.

Comment: *The url cannot be clicked separately from the info window as a whole* ... in fact, it is not even url (do not have scheme)...

Comment: in xml file:    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:background="#ADD8E6"
        android:text="www.google.gr"
        android:linksClickable="true"/>

Comment: Yup, even with autoLink set like this the info window click listener is still your only option.